# Splitting Array<String> column in dataframe to different columns with those individual strings

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Example
In a column of a dataframe, an entry is [a,b,c,d] which is an array of strings.
I want to make 4 news columns containing those individual strings.
If another entry in the column is [a,b,c]
then for that entry, the three columns will contain a,b,c and the fourth column would be empty (null) .
I want to do this in Java.
Thanks

// first converting the array to string    `UniGrams.withColumn("Unigrams",UniGrams.col("Unigrams").cast(DataTypes.StringType));`

the above step actually doesn't convert into a string due to which the below step also does not work

//  then splitting the string into columns by a comma as delimiter

```
UniGrams.selectExpr("redemptionAddress_locality_name","words","words2","split(Unigrams, ',')[0] as Unigrams1","split(Unigrams, ',')[1] as Unigrams2");
```

Comment: Please post that into question and tell us why your attempt isn't working for you.

Comment: I added that. Please try to help me

Comment: your approach will not work 'cause that way you have to state how many values are in array up-front. Try selecting array as-is, then adding columns to resultset as you process incoming data.